# Slide effect with ngAnimate

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I try to get a slide effect with angular and `ngAnimate`.
I works nicely as a fade-in/fade-out effect with `opacity`.

```
.show-animation {
  -webkit-transition: 1s all linear;
   transition:all linear 1s;
   opacity: 1;
 }

.show-animation.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/1bnpqpy8/10/

But when I try to use the `max-height` attribute for a slide effect it does not work anymore.

```
.show-animation {
  -webkit-transition: 1s all linear;
   transition:all linear 1s;
   max-height: 25px;
 }

.show-animation.ng-hide {
  max-height: 0;
}
```

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/1bnpqpy8/11/

Why does `ngAnimate` not work with `max-height`?
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an important css property: `overflow`.

overflow tells a div what to do if the contents are greater than height (or max-height). The default value is `visible` and since one of your inner divs has a set height (`timelineVoid` set to `20px`), this will force the div to be visible.

You need overflow (specifically overflow-y) set to hidden in your `show-anomation` div to allow content to be hidden:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

here is the fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/5mr8azvn/